# Strange type info of an instance of a class in Python OOP

Tags: python, class

I am trying to determine the type info of an object.

```
>>> class Class1: pass

>>> obj1=Class1()
>>> type(obj1)
<type 'instance'>
```

I was expecting the `type(obj1)` returns `'Class1'`. Why it is `'instance'` instead? What's the type `'instance'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python2 if a class doesn't inherits from `object`(directly or indirectly) then it is treated as an old-style class. And in old-style classes all instances are of type `'instance'`.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes):

> The concept of (old-style) class is unrelated to the concept of `type`:
>   if `x` is an instance of an old-style class, then `x.__class__` designates
>   the class of x, but `type(x)` is always `<type 'instance'>`.

Change you class to inherit from `object` to make it a new-style class:

```
class Class1(object): pass
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> class Class1(object): pass

>>> type(Class1())
<class '__main__.Class1'>
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, a class is old-style if it doesn't have a metaclass. But in substance this is correct. +1.

Answer (score 3):

It's one of the difference between [new-style and classic classes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) in Python 2.x. Indeed:

> The concept of (old-style) class is unrelated to the concept of type: if `x` is an instance of an old-style class, **then `x.__class__` designates the class of `x`, but `type(x)` is always `<type 'instance'>`**.

You have to use new style classes, by inheriting from `object` to get the expected `type()` result.

```
>>> class C1: pass
...
>>> class C2(object): pass
...
>>> type(C1())
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(C2())
<class '__main__.C2'>
```